SQL : How to subquery using outer alias with case expression
How can I create a subquery that uses the value of an outer column for a subquery which uses a case expression?
SQL Example:
SELECT
    name,
    average,
    crnt,
    goodFactor
FROM
(
 "Crispy Taco" AS name,
  ( SELECT avg(x)
    FROM (
     SELECT COUNT() x
     FROM tacos
     WHERE orderDate > DATEADD(DAY,  -1, GETDATE()))   <--- THE AVERAGE PRIOR TO TODAY
  ) AS average,
  COUNT(*) AS crnt,
  (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN crnt < average    <---- PROBLEM HERE : Missing columns 'crnt' and 'average'
     THEN "not good"
     ELSE "pretty good"
    END
  ) AS goodFactor
)
from tacos

The problem:
'crnt' and 'average' are 'missing columns' for the 'goodFactor' subquery
Sample Data : (database entries)
+-------------+---------+---------+
|    Name     | Ordered |  Date   |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/29/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/29/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/29/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/29/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/29/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/30/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/30/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/30/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/30/24 |
| Crispy Taco |       1 | 8/30/24 |
| Crispy Taco |      12 | 8/31/24 | <---- ASSUME QUERY INVOKED THIS DAY PRODUCING THE TABLE BELOW
+-------------+---------+---------+

The expected results:
if 'crnt' value is greater than the computed 'average'
then return "pretty good" else return "not good"
Expected Result
+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+
|    Name     | Daily Average | Current | GoodFactor         |
+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+
| Crispy Taco |       5       |      12 | pretty Good        |
+-------------+---------------+---------+--------------------+


A LATERAL derived table can reference columns from preceding tables/subqueries in the same FROM clause.

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. Also add a tag for the dbms used. (Not all of them support lateral derived tables.)

Too many problems above. Take smaller steps. BTW, current is a ISO/ANSI SQL reserved word. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Your SQL makes so little sense that it's impossible to backwards engineer to fix. Please share sample data that is in your table(s) that leads to your desired results. As it stands, there is absolutely no reason to put your case expression inside a subquery, but I suspect we are missing something important.

@JNevill sample database entries added

I don't see a need for a subquery: SELECT Name, Avg(Ordered) Average, COUNT(*) as Current, CASE WHEN Avg(Ordered) < Count(*) THEN 'Pretty Good' ELSE 'not good' END as GoodFactor FROM yourtable GROUP BY Name; Depending on your RDBMS you may also get away with CASE WHEN Average < Current THEN 'Pretty Good' ELSE 'Not Good' END

@JNevill I understand this can be achieved without using the subquery. I want to know how to make the subquery work for more complex SQL statements. The result of my poorly crafted question is in efforts to make a more simple problem to the viewers of the question

In that case, can you share which RDBMS (and version). My gut tells me that whatever problem you might encounter where you think this would be part of the solution, is likely solved through a different sql pattern. In 15 years of data engineering I've never needed to reference a parent column in a subquery (short of a correlated subquery, and even that is solving problems that are better solved with window functions).

This should work in all standard DBMS-s - today on 31st August 2024, that is, otherwise you
will have to replace CURRENT_DATE with 31st August 2024, everywhere, with that sample data:
WITH                                                                                                                                                                           
-- your input , don't use in final query
indata(name,ordered,date) AS (
          SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/29/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/29/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/29/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/29/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/29/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/30/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/30/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/30/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/30/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco', 1,DATE '08/30/24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Crispy Taco',12,DATE '08/31/24'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need a query grouping by day to get the daily sums
-- before today
daily AS (
  SELECT 
    name
  , date
  , SUM(ordered) AS per_day
  FROM indata
  WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE
  GROUP BY  
    name
  , date
)
,
-- and one summing the current day
current AS (
  SELECT
    name
  , date
  , SUM(ordered) AS current
  FROM indata
  WHERE date=CURRENT_DATE
  GROUP BY
    name
  , date
)
SELECT
  daily.name
, AVG(per_day) AS "Daily Average"
, MAX(current) AS current
, CASE WHEN MAX(current) < AVG(per_day)
    THEN 'not good'
    ELSE 'pretty good'
  END AS good_factor
FROM daily
JOIN current ON daily.name = current.name
GROUP BY  
  daily.name;




name
Daily Average
current
good_factor




Crispy Taco
5
12
pretty good



